# Can you create contour lines from a WCS file in qGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am currently working on a mapping project in qGIS, and the only good DEM model I can find of SE Norway is a high-res WCS link that I have uploaded into my project. I would really like to create contour lines, so I was wondering if there is any way to do this with a DEM in WCS format. Everything I've found online deals with raster and vector files.

Thanks!

Zack Eriksen

Answer (score 0):

The WCS link should allow you to download the data to use as a raster/grid, and then you can create contours from the grid.

I am not sure about QGIS, but you can do this in Golden Software's [Surfer](https://www.goldensoftware.com/products/surfer) program. In Surfer 16, just click to create a contour map, and when asked to open the grid, click the Download button. Add the WCS server, connect to it, select the layer and region and download. The data is downloaded from the server and the contour map is created. You can save the data as a grid at that point, if you want to use it in the future.